# How to show multiple components in reactjs

Tags: android, react-native

I have written a simple application using react native for android. i want to know how do i use more than one component adjacent to each other in the `return` function. If I put a `toolbar` tag, it gives an error.

```
return (
<MovieScreen
      style={{flex: 1}}
      navigator={navigationOperations}
      movie={route.movie}
/>
);
```

Above works. Below one gives error

```
return (
<Toolbar/>
<MovieScreen
      style={{flex: 1}}
      navigator={navigationOperations}
      movie={route.movie}
/>
);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose it in a `View` tag if you think that's how you want to showcase it.

```
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Toolbar />
    <MovieScreen
      style={{flex: 1}}
      navigator={navigationOperations}
      movie={route.movie}
    />
  </View>
);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return 2 values remember? You can only return one encapsulated tag. So, wrap a view. It will work :)

```
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Toolbar />
    <MovieScreen
      style={{flex: 1}}
      navigator={navigationOperations}
      movie={route.movie}
    />
  </View>
);
```